# Replacing an emoticon in a string unless within a certain group of text

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace emoticons in a given string with an image tag only if it is not within a certain group of characters.

Given:

```
var reg = /(?!<):\/(?![^<>]*>)/g,
    string = ':/ <a href="http://blah.com">http://blah.com</a> :/',
    result = string.replace(reg, 'IMG');
```

Result: `IMG <a href="http://blah.com">httpIMG/blah.com</a> IMG`

I want to know if there is a way to ignore the replacement within the HTML tags instead of just within the `<>`.

Comment: Do not try to parse (match) HTML with regex! Use the DOM!

Comment: Problem was the string was not part of the DOM yet and I didn't want to add it until it was formatted. I worked around this by using an element that is never added to the DOM—see my answer below (which I can't mark as an answer yet).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the best solution but if you use jQuery the following *"oneliner"* can do the job:

```
var str = ":/ <a href='http://blah.com'>http://blah.com</a> :/";

$("<div />", { html : str }).contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/:\//g, "IMG");
}).end().html();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Hfnje/

Comment: I tried this out and while that example works as expected, I actually want "IMG" to be an HTML tag. Unfortunately just replacing it with HTML does not work since the nodeType doesn't change; it appears as it would were it &lt; and &gt; instead of < or >. Thanks for the suggestion, though, maybe I can do something with it!

Answer (score 0):

why not match it against word boundaries?

```
/\B:\/\B/
```

which would match:
:/
foo :/ bar

but not:
http://
foo:/bar

Comment: I'd like to be able to replace :/:/ or hey:D so I'd like to stay clear of that for now, unless there's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

With help from @VisioN, I managed to come up with this:

```
message =
  $('<div />', html: message).contents().each(->
    if @nodeType is 3
      for replacement, emoticons of self.emoticons
        for emoticon in emoticons
          @nodeValue = @nodeValue.replace new RegExp(emoticon, 'g'),
            $('<span />', class:'emoticon ' + replacement, title: emoticon)[0].outerHTML

      $(@).replaceWith @nodeValue
  ).end().html()
```

It's not pretty, but it's working.